# Position Element on bottom right corner of scrollable div

Tags: css

I'm trying to place a button on bottom right corner of a div which is scrollable.
Since it is a content editable div, when content in the div increases, scollbar appears and button gets hidden behind the scrollbar on IE.
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I made an example for you.
Wrap all in a container, and position the bottom in the wrapper

```
main{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;

}
div{
  background:#fff;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding:10px 20px
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8f0Loem5/

hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying to place it the bottom right corner like https://www.screencast.com/t/7pCksBuu0Guu . Now in this case it goes behind the scroll bar. If I put it the way you have recommeded, there's extra space on right and bottom when there are not scrollbars - vertical & horizontal.

Comment: It is because of the padding, i forgot to set box-sizing. Remove the padding and the button is above the scrollbar in the corner